# Solution of a limit of a sequence $\frac{\sqrt{4n^2+1}-2n}{\sqrt{n^2-1}-n}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I'm trying to solve the limit of this sequence without the use an upper bound o asymptotic methods:

$$\lim_{n\longrightarrow\infty}\frac{\sqrt{4n^2+1}-2n}{\sqrt{n^2-1}-n}=\left(\frac{\infty-\infty}{\infty-\infty}\right)$$

Here there are my differents methods:

1. assuming $f(n)=\sqrt{4n^2+1}, \,$$\ g(n)=2n$, $h(n)=\sqrt{n^2-1}$, $\ \psi(n)= n$ $$f(n)-g(n)=\frac{\dfrac{1}{g(n)}-\dfrac{1}{f(n)}}{\dfrac{1}{f(n)\cdot g(n)}}, \quad h(n)-\psi(n)=\frac{\dfrac{1}{\psi(n)}-\dfrac{1}{h(n)}}{\dfrac{1}{h(n)\cdot \psi(n)}}$$
   I always have an undetermined form.
2. I've done some rationalizations:
   $$\lim_{n\longrightarrow\infty}\frac{\sqrt{4n^2+1}-2n}{\sqrt{n^2-1}-n}=\lim_{n\longrightarrow\infty}\frac{\sqrt{4n^2+1}-2n}{\sqrt{n^2-1}-n}\cdot \frac{\sqrt{4n^2+1}+2n}{\sqrt{4n^2+1}+2n}$$ where to the numerator I find $1$ and to the denominator an undetermined form. Similar situation considering
   $$\lim_{n\longrightarrow\infty}\frac{\sqrt{4n^2+1}-2n}{\sqrt{n^2-1}-n}=\lim_{n\longrightarrow\infty}\frac{\sqrt{4n^2+1}-2n}{\sqrt{n^2-1}-n}\cdot \frac{\sqrt{n^2-1}+n}{\sqrt{n^2-1}+n}$$
3. $$\frac{\sqrt{4n^2+1}-2n}{\sqrt{n^2-1}-n}=\frac{n\left(\sqrt{4+\dfrac{1}{n^2}}-2\right)}{n\left(\sqrt{1-\dfrac{1}{n^2}}-1\right)}\rightsquigarrow \left(\frac{0}{0}\right)$$
   At the moment I am not able to think about other possible simple solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note
\begin{eqnarray}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{4n^2+1}-2n}{\sqrt{n^2-1}-n}&=&\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(\sqrt{4n^2+1}-2n)(\sqrt{4n^2+1}+2n)}{(\sqrt{n^2-1}-n)(\sqrt{n^2-1}+n)}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{n^2-1}+n}{\sqrt{4n^2+1}+2n}\\
&=&-\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{n^2-1}+n}{\sqrt{4n^2+1}+2n}\\
&=&-\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{1-\frac1{n^2}}+1}{\sqrt{4+\frac1{n^2}}+2}\\
&=&-\frac12.
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: In the meantime, thanks to you, too. You're right, I had to apply rationalization twice. It didn't really occur to me. I'm out of shape. Thank you very much and I renew my gratitude.

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**:

$$\begin{align}
{\sqrt{4n^2+1}-2n\over\sqrt{n^2-1}-n}
&={\sqrt{4n^2+1}-2n\over\sqrt{n^2-1}-n}\cdot{\sqrt{4n^2+1}+2n\over\sqrt{4n^2+1}+2n}\cdot{\sqrt{n^2-1}+n\over\sqrt{n^2-1}+n}\\
&={(4n^2+1)-4n^2\over(n^2-1)-n^2}{\sqrt{n^2-1}+n\over\sqrt{4n^2+1}+2n}
\end{align}$$

Comment: What do I vote with a green check mark now? Thank you very much. I will now also thank you differently. :-)

Answer (score 2):

From here

$$\frac{\sqrt{4n^2+1}-2n}{\sqrt{n^2-1}-n}=\frac{\sqrt{4+\dfrac{1}{n^2}}-2}{\sqrt{1-\dfrac{1}{n^2}}-1}$$

we can use that

$$\sqrt{4+\dfrac{1}{n^2}}=2\sqrt{1+\dfrac{1}{4n^2}}\sim 2\left(1+\dfrac{1}{8n^2}\right)=2+\dfrac{1}{4n^2}$$

$$\sqrt{1-\dfrac{1}{n^2}}\sim 1-\dfrac{1}{2n^2}$$

Comment: Always THANK YOU with all my heart. Have you applied a Taylor expansion where there are the two symbols $\sim$  i.e. $2\sqrt{1+\dfrac{1}{4n^2}}\sim 2\left(1+\dfrac{1}{8n^2}\right)$ and $\sqrt{1-\dfrac{1}{n^2}}\sim 1-\dfrac{1}{2n^2}$? I am very sorry, but my students would not understand this approximation. The limit on the text is $-1/2$. Do you think it could be?

Comment: We are using the [Binomial approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_approximation). Yes of course the limit is $-1/2$.